# SQL summing a column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

So I have a table with a bunch of orders. Each order has a purchase order number (5th column). My table contains all line values of each order number. For example, order 3130148 has 5 items that were ordered so it has 5 lines.

```
Company_Code    Division_Code   Date_Entered    Customer_Number Customer_Purchase_Order_Number  Item_Number Color_Code  Quantity_Ordered    Description Ship_Via_Code   Order_Value Order_Status    Line_Status Price

3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130183 3102043203L     41420   1   COTTON 4PK BIKINI BRIEF SGRD    0   30  80  12
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130183 3102132003S     2221    1   STRETCH 3PK NO SHOW BRIEF   SGRD    0   30  80  39
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130148 3102012503L     46135   1   COTTON 1PK LONG SLEEVE HENLEY   SGRD    58  45  70  9
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130148 3102012503L     60120   1   COTTON 1PK LONG SLEEVE HENLEY   SGRD    58  45  70  9
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130148 3104312001L     40136   1   43100 GRAPHIC COTTON NO-SHOW BREIF  SGRD    58  45  80  9.6
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130148 3104832001L     46263   1   STRETCH M&M NO SHOW BRIEF   SGRD    58  45  70  20
3   1   00:00.0 ECOM2X      3130148 3104832001L     55112   1   STRETCH M&M NO SHOW BRIEF   SGRD    58  45  70  20
3   1   48:28.1 ECOM2X      3130143 3104235901S     69615   1   SLIQ MICRO SLIQ BRIEF   SGRD    60  45  70  9
3   1   48:28.1 ECOM2X      3130143 3104235901S     90502   1   SLIQ MICRO SLIQ BRIEF   SGRD    60  45  70  9
3   1   48:28.1 ECOM2X      3130143 3104234301S     90702   1   SLIQ MICRO SLIQ TRUNK   SGRD    60  45  70  9
```

Right now I am trying to calculate totals. Like total quantity ordered, total of each shipping code used, etc. The one I'm having a problem with is Total Value of all orders combined. My table has an order value column. However, since the table is split up by each line item, I can't just sum up the whole Order_Value column since there is a lot of duplicates (one for each line). So I need to sum all order values where the Purchase Order Number is different.

This is the line of coded I used but it is not working

```
Sum(Order_ValueG) FROM (SELECT MAX(Order_Value) AS Order_ValueG FROM T GROUP BY Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) T2 --AS Total_Orders_Value
```

I found this code here -> [SUM(DISTINCT) Based on Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782292/sumdistinct-based-on-other-columns)

I tried changing the line many times but I can't seem to get it to work. I get an error about my AS keywords.

Here is the full code (I select everything after the begin statement and run that)

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Z_N_ECOM_ORDER_STATUS_ORDERTOTAL]

@CompanyCode    VARCHAR(5),
@DivisionCode   VARCHAR(5),
@FromDate       DATETIME,
@ToDate         DATETIME
AS

DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalCompanyCode = @CompanyCode

DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalDivisionCode = @DivisionCode

DECLARE @LocalFromDate DATETIME
SET @LocalFromDate = @FromDate

DECLARE @LocalToDate DATETIME
SET @LocalToDate = @ToDate

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
    SET @LocalCompanyCode = '03'
    DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
    SET @LocalDivisionCode = '001'
    DECLARE @LocalFromDate DATETIME
    SET @LocalFromDate = '1/25/2019'
    DECLARE @LocalToDate DATETIME
    SET @LocalToDate = '1/30/2019'

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.Item_Number 
    ,T.Description
    ,Sum(T.Quantity_Ordered) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Item_Number) as Total_Items_Ordered_Number
    ,T.color_code
    ,Sum(T.Quantity_Ordered) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Item_Number, T.Color_Code) as Total_Items_Ordered_NumberColor

    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Ship_Via_Code ORDER BY T.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number ASC) 
        + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Ship_Via_Code ORDER BY T.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number DESC) 
            - 1 AS ShipCode

    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code ORDER BY T.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number ASC) 
        + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code ORDER BY T.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number DESC) 
             AS Total_Orders_Count

    ,Sum(Order_ValueG) FROM (SELECT MAX(Order_Value) AS Order_ValueG FROM T GROUP BY Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) T2 --AS Total_Orders_Value   

    /*,Sum(T.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code) as Price
    ,Sum(T.Discount_Value) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code) as Discount_Value
    ,Sum(T.Freight_Charges) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code) as Freight_Charges
    ,Sum(T.Tax_Value) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Company_Code) as Tax_Value*/ 

    FROM(

        /*DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
        SET @LocalCompanyCode = '03'
        DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
        SET @LocalDivisionCode = '001'
        DECLARE @LocalFromDate DATETIME
        SET @LocalFromDate = '1/25/2019'
        DECLARE @LocalToDate DATETIME
        SET @LocalToDate = '1/30/2019'*/

        SELECT
         O.Company_Code
        ,O.Division_Code
        ,O.Date_Entered
        ,O.Customer_Number
        ,O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number
        ,OD.Item_Number
        ,OD.Color_Code
        ,OD.Quantity_Ordered
        ,S.Description
        ,O.Ship_Via_Code --calculate count of each code
        ,O.Order_Value -- calculate how much money made from all orders (should match sum of all money made per item)
        ,O.Order_Status --calculate how many orders were cancelled (30)
        ,OD.Line_Status --calculate how many items were cancelled (80)
        ,OD.Price -- calculate how much money made per item
        ,OD.Discount_Value
        ,OD.Discount_Percentage
        ,OD.Tax_Value
        ,OD.Tax_Percentage
        ,OD.Freight_Charges
        ,OD.Freight_Percentage

        FROM 

        [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders O (nolock)

        LEFT JOIN 
        [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Detail OD (nolock) On O.Company_Code =
            OD.Company_Code And O.Division_Code =
            OD.Division_Code And O.Control_Number =
            OD.Control_Number

        LEFT JOIN
        [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style S (nolock) On OD.Company_Code = S.Company_Code And
            OD.Division_Code = S.Division_Code And
            OD.Item_Number = S.Item_Number And
            OD.Color_Code = S.Color_Code

        WHERE 
        (O.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL) AND 
        (O.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL) AND
        o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x' AND 
        o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number not like '%bulk%' AND
        o.Date_Entered BETWEEN @LocalFromDate AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, @LocalToDate)

        --order by date_entered desc
        --order by Customer_Purchase_Order_Number desc

        ) AS T 

    ORDER BY Total_Items_Ordered_Number desc, Total_Items_Ordered_NumberColor desc

END
```

I think the error has to do with me trying to use the Table T in my subquery. If this was a simple query, I would just GROUP BY Customer_Purchase_Order_Number but since I am selecting multiple things, that doesn't work.

Comment: you can use the sum in the order value grouping by Customer_Purchase_Order_Number and order id and make it as a subquery and join with your order tables to get the other fields. Would that be simple enough ?

Comment: Also you should be able to solve this by SUMming a CASE expression.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't understand, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok well the code you posted is too broken to be useful and you haven't shared your DDL or raw data, so I'm going to give you some direction in psuedo code.

> So I need to sum all order values where the Purchase Order Number is different.

You can do something like:

```
SUM(CASE
  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PurchaseOrderNumber ORDER BY SomeColumn)=1 THEN OrderValue
  ELSE 0
END) AS SumValues
```